# ¿Como resuelvo "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException:"?

Tags: java

El Codigo en el cual me sale ese error esta hecho en java y es el siguiente:

```
        
        String userWord;
        int wordSelection = 0;//(int)(Math.random()*6);
        String wordR = words[wordSelection];
        String[] asterisk = new String[words[wordSelection].length()];
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int word = words[wordSelection].length();
        if (wordSelection == 0){
            
            for (int i = 0; i <= word; i++) {
                
                asterisk[i] = "*";
            }
            
            while (count < 7) {
                System.out.println("Guess any letter in the word");
                System.out.println(asterisk[0]+asterisk[1]+asterisk[2]+asterisk[3]+asterisk[4]+asterisk[5]+asterisk[6]);
                userWord = sc.next();   
                
                for (int i = 0;i <= words[wordSelection].length(); i++) {
                    if (userWord.charAt(0) == wordR.charAt(i)){
                        if (userWord.toLowerCase() == "c"){
                            asterisk[i] = "c";
                            
                            
                        }
```

El error que aparece es:

[image: esos son los errores que me aparecen]

Ese codigo pertenece a un ahorcado el cual estoy haciendo en java.
Nose por que esta mal.
Y tampoco se de que manera solucionarlo,gracias.

Comment: debes poner i < word, actualmente tienes i<=word

Comment: _No sé por qué está mal, y tampoco se de qué manera solucionarlo_: De hecho, el error te lo dice: *String index out of range* => índice de cadena fuera de rango :)

Comment: @Japv porque el <= ni funciona?

Comment: @Boomcher lo probaste y sirvio?

Comment: @Japv si funciono,gracias